# How to append element to key type list, element is type dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, redis, redis-py

I have below code, I can create a key type list, and its element is type dictionary?

Sorry, My english is not good.

```
field_list = [
    {'name': 'abc', 'age': 22},
    {'name': 'dec', 'age': 34},
    {'name': 'xyz', 'age': 65},
    {'name': 'wqe', 'age': 32},
    {'name': 'edc', 'age': 34},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis Lists store string values, so you'd need to encode your data to some string representation, store it in the Redis list, then decode it when you get it out.  JSON would be a good option for this, so with redis-py you'd need something that looks like this which you could adapt to your needs:

```
import json
import redis

data_to_push_to_list = [
    {'name': 'abc', 'age': 22},
    {'name': 'dec', 'age': 34},
    {'name': 'xyz', 'age': 65},
    {'name': 'wqe', 'age': 32},
    {'name': 'edc', 'age': 34},
]

redisClient = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)

for list_item in data_to_push_to_list:
    json_string = json.dumps(list_item)
    redisClient.lpush('mylist', json_string)
```

This will result in a list at key `mylist` that looks like this in Redis:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> type mylist
list
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange mylist 0 -1
1) "{\"name\": \"edc\", \"age\": 34}"
2) "{\"name\": \"wqe\", \"age\": 32}"
3) "{\"name\": \"xyz\", \"age\": 65}"
4) "{\"name\": \"dec\", \"age\": 34}"
5) "{\"name\": \"abc\", \"age\": 22}"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

To get the data back out in Python (I'm using `rpop` to pop the data off the other end of the list):

```
import json
import redis

redisClient = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)

list_item_as_string = redisClient.rpop('mylist')

while list_item_as_string is not None:
  list_item_as_dict = json.loads(list_item_as_string)
  print(list_item_as_dict)
  list_item_as_string = redisClient.rpop('mylist')
```

See the Redis [LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush) and [RPOP](https://redis.io/commands/rpop) command documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I found this solution yesterday, but still thank you my score is lower than 15 so can't vote for you.

Comment: No problem, glad you got up and running with it.